# UIBarButtonItem action method does not work in certain cases

Tags: ios, swift

### Current problems and things I want to know

UIBarButtonItem action method does not work in certain cases. I want to know why it just doesn't work.

### Case1

[case1 storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI3I0.png)

Just added NavigationController to the default ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let okButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(okButtonTapped(_:)))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = okButton
    }

    @objc func okButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("OK!")
    }
}
```

In this case, the OK button does not work.
There is no error message.

### Case2

[case2 storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soPU2.png)

Added Navigation Bar to default ViewController.
UINavigationItem connects to the outlet with the name myNavigationItem.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myNavigationItem: UINavigationItem!

    let okButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(okButtonTapped(_:)))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myNavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = okButton
    }

    @objc func okButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("OK!")
    }
}
```

In this case, the OK button work.

### Summary

I understand that even in case 1, if okButton initialization is executed in viewDidLoad, it will work.
I want to know why case2 works but case1 doesn't work.

Thnak you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I summarized it because I solved it myself.

1. During initialization of instance properties, `self` cannot be used because the instance itself has not yet been created. However, it is treated as `nil` without causing an error. This is true for both cases.
2. If target is set to `nil`, it will be executed when an action method (`ngButtonTapped`) is found going up the View hierarchy.
3. In case1, there is no `ViewController` above the navigation bar, so no action method is found and nothing happens. (The VIew hierarchy can be confirmed with the Xcode view debugger)
4. In Case2, the action method (`ngButtonTapped`) is executed because `ViewController` is located above the navigation bar.

Answer (score 2):

If you initialise the `okButton` before `viewDidLoad` you can't set the target `self`. So initialise the button in `viewDidLoad`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var okButton:UIBarButtonItem?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        okButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(okButtonTapped(_:)))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = okButton
    }

    @objc func okButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("OK!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Or make it lazy var

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I still don't understand a little.
Why can’t I set the target `self` before `viewDidLoad` only in Case 1.
The `self` is an instance of `ViewController`, right?

Comment: @capibara because self is not initialised yet before viewdidload

Answer (score 0):

If you need the button to be accessible for the entire class, just declare it as you did, but initialise it in viewDidLoad.
Case 2 works because the storyboard gives you the myNavigationItem when view did load is called. Check the value of self.navigationItem in Case 1 in viewDidLoad.